# Adobe RoboHelp 9: What's the best way to make more than one conditional build available to the same application?

Tags: robohelp, help-authoring

I am creating a WebHelp help system with RoboHelp 9. This will be context-sensitive, online help. The software product that the system is written for has three user "contexts" that are mostly similar, but have slight differences. My goal is to display only the help content that is relevant to a user.

To illustrate my problem: In the application, when User A adds a Foo, he sees fields 1, 2, and 3; however, when User B adds a Foo, he sees fields 1, 2, and *4*. When User A clicks the Help link on the Add screen, he should see the help topic that describes exactly what he sees. When User B clicks the Help link, he should see the content that's been tailored to what he sees.

To achieve this goal, I am in the process of adding condition indicators at the text level (within topics) for the different contexts of the software.

My question is, when the time comes to output the help system, do I need to generate three complete help systems using the conditional build tags, one for each context? Then when the developers plug in the context map IDs, do they need to pass a different location for the a_pszHelpFile parameter to access the correct help system?

The above is the only way I can think of to ensure that the TOC and topic text is correct for each type of user who may click the Help link on any given page, but it seems clunky to generate an entire help system for each conditional build tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you guessed right. We have the same scenario here, using the same scenario you described.